# How to use a variable in a Nodejs command

Tags: node.js, mongodb, variables

So i have some variables, that contains strings. I would like to access my mongodb using these strings, but of course it won't work if i just write it down like that:

```
...some db connection code
var x="name";
...find all data, then loop
..function(err,docs){
docs[i].x;
}
```

The queastion is, how can i access the X parameters of my collection.

Comment: what are strings? (some column-name or some value), and which element are you looping on?

Comment: The answer of Kevin works just fine. I screwed up my question a bit. The strings are column names btw, and i am looping on rows of data(my code above is bad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this way :

```
database.mydata[i][x];
```